# What causes differences in global variables (interactive vs. scripts)

Tags: node.js

I'm running to the following issue with Node.js <sup>`v0.10.1`</sup> (demonstrated with a quick example):

While running node in the interactive command line:

```js
> global.require
{ [Function: require] . . . }
> require
{ [Function: require] . . . }
```

When running the following `script.js` I get unexpected results:

```js
console.log(global.require);     // 1.
console.log(require);            // 2.
```

```js
undefined                        // 1. `global.require` is undefined!
{ [Function: require] . . .}     // 2. `require` by itself works however.
```

<sub>I've removed extra code denoted by `...`. Run it locally to see the full extent of what is actually shown.</sub>

What causes this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js contains a [repl](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) module that allows you to create your own Read-Evaluate-Print-Loops (this is what `repl` stands for). Using this module there is a function [start](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_start_options) that you use to create a new repl.

This function takes an `options`  object where you can configure your repl. One of these options is called `useGlobal`. According to the documentation for this option the following sentence is valid:

> if set to `true`, then the repl will use the `global` object, instead of running scripts in a separate context. Defaults to `false`.

Now when you start Node.js in interactive mode, this is basically nothing but a repl like those you could create for yourself using the `repl` module. I guess (and please note that this is only a guess!) that Node.js's default repl has `useGlobal` set to `true`.

Hence you have a `global` object, which is in turn the very same as the global namespace anyway. Hence all the functions such as `require` that you can find on the global namespace you will again find on the `global` object.

Once you start a Node.js application in non-interactive mode, there is no repl, hence there is no `global` object.

Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 2):

Many of the [Globals](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global_objects) won't normally be in the global scope or members of the [`global`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) object:

> These objects are available in all modules. **Some of these objects aren't actually in the global scope but in the module scope - this will be noted.**

These are "*globals*" more by the 2nd interpretation:

- Of the top-most scope.
- Of an accessible scope other than the current local scope.

Also, as noted for [`require()`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require):

> To require modules. See the [Modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) section. **`require` isn't actually a global but rather local to each module.**

The [REPL module](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html), that manages the interactive mode, has an option to *promote* them to the global scope:

> `useGlobal` - if set to `true`, then the repl will use the `global` object, instead of running scripts in a separate context. Defaults to `false`.